# Property from Expression in Shell Script

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, network, shell, syntaxerror

I am using qgis_process in a shell script (Linux) to make a buffer using a field as the distance. I can get *a* buffer from the shell with

```
qgis_process run qgis:buffer INPUT=pt.shp OUTPUT=buffered.shp DISTANCE=12
```

This makes a 12-meter buffer from the file `pt.shp`, which is a single point, and saves it as `buffered.shp`. It works, cool. The input file has a field `radius` which has the value I want to use as the buffer distance. How do I do this?

The GUI is well-suited for this, and it says it is feeding the parameter

```
'DISTANCE' : QgsProperty.fromExpression('"radius"')
```

into the buffer call. This came from the GUI log. I tried

```
qgis_process run qgis:buffer INPUT=pt.shp OUTPUT=buffered.shp DISTANCE="QgsProperty.fromExpression('\"radius\"')"
```

but I got an error about invalid value for distance. I also tried all the quotation arrangements I could think of, since I suspect I am just not escaping/encoding the string correctly. So did I just not find the right string-syntax that makes it work?

---

For context, I am actually performing a large calculation with QGIS as a learning exercise. I have data for the population-weighted centroids (pwc) of Minnesota, the pharmacies of Minnesota, and all the roads in Minnesota. I am trying to find the average road-network distance for the citizens of Minnesota to their nearest 5 pharmacies. The network distance tool I found for this is QNEAT3's OD matrix, but my network and points were just too much. It was trying to compute the minimal distance from every pwc to every pharmacy, using the statewide road network. The result was corrupted, probably because that is too big a task to compute directly. So I have come up with an alternative process which I can spell out just in case it helps.

Step 1: Split the pwcs from one point file with many features into single-featured point files. There are 1334 of these.

Step 2: Do some euclidean analysis to find the distance to the 10th nearest pharmacy for each pwc. Add a kilometer to this value (for good measure), multiply it by 1.5 (ditto), and presumably the nearest 5 pharmacies (by road) with be within this distance (euclidean) of the pwc. This is the radius from above.

Step 3: Buffer the pwcs by this radius, with the intention of localizing the statewide problem to these small chunks of the state.

Step 4: For each of the 1334 buffered pieces, intersect the pharmacies and roads to them. These are now small networks which the OD matrix tool can handle, so run the analysis individually on each one.

Step 5: Combine the results of the 1334 individual calculations and get the final answer.

At this point I personally want to finish this calculation using this process because it involves a lot of learning new tricks, but if you have an alternate way to solve this problem I would love to hear it.